# If a sequence converges to a, prove the squares of its terms converge to a^2

Tags: real-analysis

Given:
$$a_n\to a$$ 
 That means :
For all $\epsilon^*:=\frac{\epsilon }{2|a|+1} $  we can find an N such that for all n>N $\left |a_n-a  \right |<\frac{\epsilon }{2|a|+1}$

I have to prove
$$(a_n)^2 \to a^2 $$

At first we guess 
$\left |a_n+a  \right |=\left |a_n-a+a+a  \right |<\frac{\epsilon }{2|a|+1 }+2|a | $

Now we can prove

$$(a_n)^2 \to a^2 $$
$\left |(a_n)^2-   a^2 \right |=\left |(a_n-a)(a_n+a)\right |=\left |a_n-a  \right |\left |a_n+a  \right |<\frac{\epsilon }{2|a|+1}(\frac{\epsilon }{2|a|+1}+2|a |)<\epsilon^2+\epsilon$

I changed my epsilon and i think it works now??
any suggestion ?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you trying to prove that if some sequence $a_n\in\mathbb R$ converges to $a$, then its square converges to $a^2$?

Comment: i have to prove if a_n converges to a, then (a_n)^2 convergens to a^2

Comment: $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = a$ means that for all $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exists natural number $N$ such that for all $n \gt N$, $|a_n - a| \lt \epsilon$.

Comment: This is good, but to finish you need to show that you can make $\epsilon^*$ as small as you want. It is not difficult, but it is the essence of the proof.

Comment: @Beginner how is $\frac{\epsilon}{2|a| + \epsilon}(\frac{\epsilon}{2|a|} + 2|a|) < \epsilon$? Putting aside the fact that $a$ can be zero (in which case $\epsilon/|a|$ is undefined), if $\epsilon = 2$ and $a = 1/4$, then the left hand side of the inequality is equal to $45/8$, but the right hand side is equal to $2$, which is less than $45/8$.

Comment: ture! i changed again...

Comment: @Beginner you would've been able to make $|a_n^2 - a^2| < \epsilon$ for $n > N$ if you let $\epsilon^*$ to be the smaller of the numbers $1$ and $\epsilon/(1 + 2|a|)$. That's why I chose $\eta$ (in your notation, $\epsilon^*$) to be $\min\{1, \epsilon/(1 + 2|a|)\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\varepsilon > 0$, let $\eta := \min\{1, \frac{\varepsilon}{(1 + 2|a|)}\} > 0$.

So since $a_n \to a$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $|a_n - a| < \eta$ for all $n \ge N$.

Now if $n \ge N$, then in particular, $|a_n - a| < 1$, which implies
$$
|a_n + a| = |(a_n - a) + 2a| \le |a_n -a| + 2|a| < 1 + 2|a|
$$
Thus
$$
|a_n^2 - a^2| = |a_n + a||a_n - a| < (1 + 2|a|) \frac{\varepsilon}{1 + 2|a|} = \varepsilon$$
Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, $~a_n^2 \to a^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and can you tell me please, is my solution correct?

Comment: It's not correct. For one, $a$ can be zero, so $\varepsilon/a$ may be undefined.

Comment: For all $\frac{\epsilon }{2|a|+frac{\epsilon}}$  we can find an N such that for all n>N $\left |a_n-a  \right |<\frac{\epsilon }{2|a|+frac{\epsilon}}$

Comment: Your statement does not make sense. Even if you just have $|a_n - a| < \varepsilon/(\text{something})$ for all $n > N$, you cannot find an upper bound for $|a_n + a|$ that is independent of $\varepsilon$ for $n > N$.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works as a solution, so someone should check this:

Since $a_n \rightarrow a$ we know that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$ we have

$$ \lvert a_n - a \rvert \leq \lvert x_n\rvert + \lvert a\rvert < \epsilon $$
$$ \lvert a_n - a \rvert^2 \leq \left( \lvert x_n\rvert + \lvert a\rvert \right)^2 < \epsilon^2 $$

It follows that

$$ \left( \lvert x_n\rvert + \lvert a\rvert \right)^2 = x_n^2 + 2x_na + a^2 < \epsilon^2 $$
$$ \lvert x_n^2 - a^2 \rvert < x_n^2 + 2x_na + a^2 < \epsilon^2$$

So if $x_n$ converges to a then $ x_n^2 $ converges to $a^2$